# rdflib "EnumeratedClass" to create enumerated datatype

Tags: owl, rdflib

I am new to rdflib (and RDF/OWL), so I'm having some trouble understanding the rdflib documentation in the absence of concrete examples / layman's guides.

I have an OWL subClass for which I want to create three possible values. I found [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-owl-ref-20040210/#EnumeratedDatatype) official tennis example with the "end result" I assume I would need, which I wanted to recreate with my data using rdflib.

I found rdflib's ["rdflib.extras.infixowl.EnumeratedClass"](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.extras.html), and tried modifying and running the sample code, but my serialized output doesn't resemble the tennis example output.

My code:

```python
from rdflib import URIRef, BNode, Literal, Namespace, Graph
from rdflib.namespace import RDF, RDFS, OWL
from rdflib.extras.infixowl import EnumeratedClass, Individual
from rdflib.collection import Collection
from rdflib.util import first

n = Namespace("http://example.org/example/")
g = Graph()
g.bind("owl",OWL)
g.bind("", n)

my_class = n.my_class
g.add((my_class, RDF.type, OWL.Class))
g.add((my_class, RDFS.subClassOf, OWL.Thing))
g.add((my_class, RDF.ID, Literal("my_class")))

my_subclass = n.my_subclass
g.add((my_subclass, RDF.type, OWL.Class))
g.add((my_subclass, RDF.ID, Literal("my_subclass")))
g.add((my_subclass, OWL.subClassOf, my_class))

Individual.factoryGraph = g
my_list = EnumeratedClass(n.my_list,
                             members=[n.listitem1,
                                      n.listitem2,
                                      n.listitem3])

col = Collection(g, first(
    g.objects(predicate=OWL.oneOf,
              subject=my_list.identifier)))

[g.qname(item) for item in col]
```

This gives me:

```
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/example/my_subclass">
    <rdf:ID>my_subclass</rdf:ID>
    <owl:oneOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/example/listitem1"/>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/example/listitem2"/>
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/example/listitem3"/>
    </owl:oneOf>
    <owl:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://example.org/datacategories/my_class"/>
  </owl:Class>
```

and not the "first/rest" format seen in the official tennis example.

First: Is this wrong?

Second: If someone can explain to me what the effective difference is between these two formats, and whether there is a preference, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need enumerated class or enumerated datatype?

Comment: Could you please explain the difference? My aim is to define a set of values (listitem1, listitem2 OR listitem3 ) that my_subclass can have.

Comment: Members of enumerated datatype are literals (`"November"^^xsd:string` etc.), members of enumerated class are individuals (`some_prefix:November` etc.).

Comment: I want them to be literals, so I guess I need "enumerated datatype". Could you please point me to a reference for how to create this using rdflib?